# How to efficiently find pairs of nodes in a graph that when removed will cause the graph to split?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory

Consider this simple biconnected graph (graph without [articulation points](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.articulation_points.html)):

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.diamond_graph()
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image: diamond graph]

I want to find out what two pairs of nodes when removed from the graph will cause the graph to split. For example removing nodes 1 and 2 from this graph will cause the graph to have 2 components: node 3 and node 0). For this I am removing the combination of nodes one by one and counting the number of components left in the graph.

```py
from itertools import combinations

breaking_combinations = []
combos = combinations(G.nodes(), 2)
for combo in combos:
    G_copy = G.copy()
    init_num_components = nx.number_connected_components(G_copy)
    G_copy.remove_nodes_from(combo)
    num_components_after_combo_removed = nx.number_connected_components(G_copy)
    if num_components_after_combo_removed > init_num_components:
        breaking_combinations.append(combo)

print(breaking_combinations)
```

The logic works fine and I am getting the expected results: `(1, 2)` in this example. But this process is so slow on big graphs (~10,000 nodes) that it takes forever to find all combinations in the graph.

My question is: is there an efficient alternate approach I can use to achieve the same results - perhaps by using in-built networkx algorithms?

Comment: Hmmm ... sometimes removing one node only will be sufficient to split the network ... by the way: I can't see what does it exactly mean to *split a network*?

Comment: You are looking for "articulation points".  Tarjan's articulation points algorithm is the most efficient means of finding all nodes that if any one of them were removed, would split the graph in two.

Comment: @FrankYellin, `nx.diamond_graph()` is biconnected, and there won't be any articulation points in that case

Comment: Correct - The graph I am working with does not have any articulation points - it is biconnected

Comment: Surely an improvement over your current algorithm would be to remove only one node on each iteration and then use Tarjan's algorithm to identify articulation points. Your algorithm is O(V**2) for the outer loop and then O(V log(V)) for the DFS to find the components. IIRC, Tarjan's algorithms is also just O(V log(V)) so you would be removing one factor of V.

Comment: **I voted to re-open,** as the question clearly does not require more details or clarity. OP provided an MWE with working code. The toy example is well chosen (the smallest possible graph for the problem being solved). The most straight-forward approach (implemented in the MWE) does not scale to the problem size required. Using the code in the MWE, the computation would require about 60 years on a standard laptop (based on some running time tests and back-of-the envelope calculations/extrapolations), so there clearly is an issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.diamond_graph()

solutions = []
for removed_node in G:
    H = G.subgraph([node for node in G if node != removed_node]) # subgraph views are much faster to initialize than copies
    solutions.extend([(removed_node, node) for node in nx.articulation_points(H)])
print(solutions)
# (1, 2), (2, 1)
```

## Edit

I also did a little bit of testing. The results are encouraging.

```py
import networkx as nx

from itertools import combinations


def find_articulation_pairs(G):
    solutions = []
    for removed_node in G:
        H = G.subgraph([node for node in G if node != removed_node]) # subgraph views are much faster to initialize than copies
        solutions.extend([(removed_node, node) for node in nx.articulation_points(H)])
    return solutions


def find_articulation_pairs_baseline(G):
    # the original approach with minor improvements
    total_components = nx.number_connected_components(G) # no need to compute this number on each iteration
    solutions = []
    for removed_nodes in combinations(G, 2):
        H = G.subgraph([node for node in G if node not in removed_nodes])
        if nx.number_connected_components(H) > total_components:
            solutions.append(removed_nodes)
    return solutions


def test_correctness():
    G = nx.diamond_graph()
    print(find_articulation_pairs(G))
    print(find_articulation_pairs_baseline(G))


def test_running_time():
    import time

    # large random graph
    G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.1)

    # largest biconnected subgraph
    H = G.subgraph(max(nx.biconnected_components(G), key=len))

    tic = time.time()
    _ = find_articulation_pairs(H)
    toc = time.time()
    _ = find_articulation_pairs_baseline(H)
    tac = time.time()

    print(f"Baseline time: {tac-toc:.2f}")
    print(f"Improved time: {toc-tic:.2f}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_correctness()
    test_running_time()
```

Running the script results in the following output:

```py
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 2)]
Baseline time: 14.72
Improved time: 0.44
```

## Edit #2

Both approaches are trivial to parallelize, so depending on the number of available cores, there is another speed-up of factor 4-12 to achieve.

Some back of the envelope calculations suggest that for 10k nodes, the running time of my improved approach (on my machine without parallelization) would still be around 2 days, so such parallelization is probably not optional but a must.

Comment: This is brilliant and exponentially faster than what I had! And thanks for the tip about parallelizing this as well